# Como usar fontes no meu Site?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, webdesign

Olá, eu sempre usei fontes do Google em meus sites, mas me deparei com um projeto que possui fontes que não existem no Google Fonts. Posso usar fonte externa, seja ela qual for? E como? (Peço desculpa se já houver alguma pergunta parecida, mas não achei nenhuma que me tirasse todas as duvidas.)

Preciso saber também sobre fontes pagas e etc, se posso usar qualquer fonte ou posso ter algum problema com copyright.

Posso também baixar alguma fonte em meu computador e importa-la para o Google WebFonts, por exemplo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode importar a fonte em seu projeto usando CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo300';
    src: url('../fonts/museo300-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/museo300-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/museo300-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/museo300-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/museo300-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/museo300-regular-webfont.svg#museo300') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Lembrando que algumas fontes são pagas e por isso não é possível fazer a conversão para todos os formatos.

Existe diversos sites que fazem a conversão de um tipo de fonte para todos os outros.

Comment: Sendo assim eu posso baixar a fonte que eu preciso de algum site qualquer, coloca-la em uma pasta do meu site e importar ela no css, é isso?

Comment: Isso, se você tiver apenas a fonte em um determinado formato, você pode usar o site font squirrel, ele converte fontes grátis para todos os outros tipos necessários

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá importar através do Google WebFonts:
Este é um exemplo clássico de aplicação:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie:regular' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<style>
h1 { 
     font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', serif; 
     font-size: 48px; 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <h1>Seu texto vai aqui.</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

As fonts você poderá obter através do link https://www.google.com/fonts/

Comment: Certo. Mas as fontes que eu preciso não existem no Google WebFonts. Eu posso baixar uma fonte no meu computador e importar ela no Google WebFonts, é isso?

Comment: Neste caso, você pode fazer como a outra resposta, apenas te passei como alternativa!