# Como importar fonte CSS

Tags: css

Preciso utilizar a fonte [Imagine](https://www.dafont.com/imagine-font.font), porém não tenho ideia de como importá-la para minha página. Fiz assim, mas não deu certo:

```
<style>
font {font-family: "Imagine Font"; src: url("lib/font/imagine_font.ttf") format("truetype");}
</style>
```

Comment: Dúvida: Por quê fazer isso no PHP e não diretamente no CSS? Acredito que a pergunta [Como usar fontes no meu Site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100055/5878) soluciona seu problema.

Comment: Boa pergunta... Fiz diretamente em CSS agora... rs

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, fiz exatamente o que mostra no link que você mandou, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Coloca essa tentativa na pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Já está na pergunta... é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Não é, não. Na pergunta que citei é utilizado `@font-face`. Você utilizou apenas `font`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar fontes no meu Site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100055/como-usar-fontes-no-meu-site)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, font é o nome da minha tag. É como se fosse h1. Fiz a alteração que você sugeriu, mas não funcionou também.

Comment: http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/css3-@font-face.php

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você está querendo atribuir uma font carregando ela junto com o link tente por ela direto no reset da página ex:

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; font-family: "Imagine Font" Arial;}
```

tente assim mais não será 100% porque quem está acessando sua página não tiver a fonte em seu computador a mesma irá ser trocada por outra em alguns caso o texto é quebrado, por isso sempre acrescente uma outra que tenha em todos os computador.